# How to use the group by function with window aggregate functions - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with a certain query in SQL. The goal is to return the order_id, the total amount (which is just ((item_price - discount_amount) * quantity), the total amount for each order, and the average amount for each order.

For the last two columns that I am supposed to retrieve, I have to use the window aggregate functions and partition them by the order_id.

Here's my code so far

```sql
SELECT 
    order_id,
    ((item_price - discount_amount) * quantity) AS total_amount,
    SUM((item_price - discount_amount) * quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY order_id) AS order_total,
    AVG((item_price - discount_amount) * quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY order_id  ORDER BY order_id) AS Average_total
FROM order_instruments
GROUP BY order_id, ((item_price - discount_amount) * quantity);
```

However, when I run it it says that the SELECT expression #3 is not in the group by clause. But I'm not sure how to add it in the group by clause as it gives me an error message whenever I try to use the alias order_total and Average_total.

How can I fix my query here to make this work?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand your question, I think that you don't need aggregation here. Isn't the following what you need?

```
select 
    order_id,
    (item_price - discount_amount) * quantity as total_amount,
    sum((item_price - discount_amount) * quantity) over(partition by order_id) as order_total,
    avg((item_price - discount_amount) * quantity) over(partition by order_id) as average_total
from order_instruments
```